# Render div on one page without overflowing

Tags: visualforce, css, html, pdf

So I am using a Visualforce page and RenderAS PDF. I have split the page into 2 columns (as seen below). The issue I am having is when the text becomes to long, it goes onto the next page. I want to keep it all on the same page. I am unsure how to do so. I tried the following and it did not work.

So the first column data spills over to the next page. How can I keep each columns data on the same page? Also I have simplified the code to focus on the problem at hand.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf"  id="mypage" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
    <style>
      @page {
        size:landscape;           
     }

   body {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';                 
        }

   h1 { font-size: 180%; font-weight:bold;}

   h2 { font-size: 120%; font-weight:bold; 

      }     

      @media print {
        .column {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 45.00%;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      } 
     } 

    th {
        text-align: center;
    }

    td {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .column1 {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 40px;
        width: 45.00%;
    }               
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
     /* FIRST COLUMN DATA SPILLS TO NEXT PAGE*/               
      <div class="column">
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable>
          /*data*/
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>           

    <p></p>
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable>
          /*data*/
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>             
     <p></p>

        <h2>H1 </h2>
        <apex:outputText More Data />
        <p></p>
        <h2>H2</h2>
        <apex:outputText  More Data />
        <p></p>
        <h2>H3</h2>
        <apex:outputText More Data  />
        </div>

       /* SECOND COLUMN*/
    <div class="column1">            
    <h2>Sales and Services </h2>
        <apex:outputText  More Data />
    </div>

</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the width of the column in CSS property and keep the width same for all column in CSS property.
e.g.

```css
.column3 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25.00%;
}  
.column4 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 25.00%;
}
```

[![Styling applied][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyioC.png